# Converting string obtained from database into keypress event

Tags: c#, events

I have a string value in a variable. I want it to be thrown in keypress event.

When user clicks on "*Start Writing Button*". The text contained in variable gets written to the area whereever cursor has focus.

eg.
string str = "Example"

I have a web page with a textbox and a button. When user clicks on Start Reading button Example gets written on to textbox.

Basically the characters being written should be trapped on 
javascript-onKeyPress event 
Winform- KeyPress event
etc.

**EDIT**

I want to use some devices that will be throwing data constantly to my variable using window service. I need to write this data to the active window whereever the cursor has focus currently irrespective of window or web.

I copied data to clipboard and pasted on active window but this is problematic since different tabs are considered to same active window and doesn't writes.

Looking for a proper way rather then workaround I have taken.

Comment: Is this JavaScript or Windows Forms? It's hard to see how it would be both, unless you're using a browser control. Please give more details.

Comment: Okay, so that may not be Windows Forms or *anything* similar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you've clarified the question, I suspect you want [`SendKeys.SendWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx).

You'll need to be somewhat careful with it, but it may do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for very good link, will start searching in details on it. I saw the line on the article **implementation is still susceptible to timing issues**. Any Idea on how fast would it process since I usually need to send 20-30 characters in less then a second just to immitate as if data was directly written by a device. Moreover I observed its namespace to be System.Windows.Forms. Would it be available in window service ?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta: You'd need to give the service access to the desktop. Are you sure there isn't a cleaner way of achieving your greater goal? What's the real purpose of this? If it's for automated testing for example, there are plenty of bespoke products you could look at.

Comment: I know I am not able to identify the cleaner way and looking for all possible solutions. I have an HID(RFID) device just like barcode scanner. I was expecting that it would mimic keystrokes eg 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655023/how-do-i-read-input-from-a-usb-hid-device'. I need to read data from this device on a web application. I dont know capabilities of browser whether it can access the device or not. But this is my requirement.