# Reading input from a 2nd USB HID without interfering with main form

Tags: c#, input, usb, hid

having found lots of answers to questions here, I decided to ask since I found something really really close to what I want to achieve in my app.
[How to read input from a USB HID device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655023/how-do-i-read-input-from-a-usb-hid-device)

But this solution differs just a bit from what I need.
So I have one simple form in charge of counting how many "d"'s are pressed on a USB HID;
which is actually an electronic sensor connected to an iPAC which emulates the keyboard input to the PC, I use this to count how many cycles a fan is making, every time the fan passes it actives the sensor, the sensor activates the input in the iPAC, and the iPAC sends a various "d"'s to the main form, I use a simple Boolean variable along with the key up and down events to evaluate if it's a new cycle, additionally I have a couple of buttons and select boxes on the form to report and register problems, this form is connected to an Access DB, but, since the fan cycles about 3 times per seconds, it sends too much input that makes the form totally unusable and it doesn't even let me use the mouse, I it ever let's me and try to select an option from a box, it instantly populates it with hundreds of d's.

Do you have any recommendations for and API that will let me just listen to the input?
I just need to know how many cycles the fan is making.

Comment: So, if you want to know how many cycles goes. Why dont just count them in a while sentences? and avoid the "d" typing process.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the edit!; I can't eliminate the "d" typing process since that is the actual input of of every cycle that goes on, imagine that every cycle is a long "d" key down, but in between cycles there's a key up.

Comment: It's an interface, commonly used in arcades, but it simulates a USB keyboard input(the letter D in this case, when the inductive sensor is activated).