# Capture RFID Reader Cardswipe on ASP Webforms Application

Tags: c#, usb, rfid, proximity

I have this client with a USB plug and play proximity RFID reader that reads input from a card-swipe. When I open an Excel sheet and swipe the cards, the unique card numbers are copied to the sheet. Example of swiping 2 different cards.

[image]

How best to capture the card numbers to a webforms website on the event a person swipes the card?

I have created a console application to test the data capture using `LibUsbDotNet` 2.2.29 using the code here: [How to read from a USB RFID Reader with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759089/how-to-read-from-a-usb-rfid-reader-with-c-sharp)

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can provide a textfield (or textblock for multiple ids) and a submit button. This button sends this form to your server. For "real time" processing (triggered by change event) you need JavaScript and an API Controller.

Comment: That is one sure way.