# Read RFID tag using LibUsbDotNet

Tags: c#, rfid, libusbdotnet

I have a generic USB RFID card reader.

I am using code from [How to read from a usb rfid reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608485/1968973) to read the data. It seems to read okay, however, the output is a byte array. What I want to get is the RFID number, the one that's printed on the card. How can I get this?

**EDIT**

I successfully retrieved the tag number by implementing a key logger. It seems that the reader does not directly send the tag number down the wire, but rather, sends a command to type the tag number out. This solution works but I'm still open to other, more direct approaches.

Answer (score 0):

After successfully reading the RFID tag, all you need to do is to convert the byte array into a string. Please refer to the following line of code and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more details.

```
// readBuffer: The byte array containing the sequence of bytes to decode.
// 0: The index of the first byte to decode.
// bytesRead: The number of bytes to decode.
var strRfidTag = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Comment: I tried that, but the resulting text is gibberish. I think the input bytes do not represent the actual tag number, but rather, the command to type those out.