# Reading Rfid Tags using libdotnet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rfid

I use the code:
[How to read from a usb rfid reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516812/how-to-read-from-a-usb-rfid-reader/35608485#35608485)
to read RFID card but I want to read image from it. What should I do? This code working properly but I have no idea of reading and extracting image from it? Pease guide me!

Comment: Please add information such as the manual, SDK, device driver, etc. of which device of which vendor you are using.

Comment: I am using a RFID reader:
http://www.robicom-cs.com/detail-47.html

Comment: Unfortunately, looking at the pages introduced, it seems difficult to get advice and answers, as there seems to be no information on manuals, SDKs, and device drivers. Please contact the vendor directly.

Comment: I just want to know if there is any c# library that help me to read only image tags

Comment: Most devices have their own command / response specifications. Unless the device you're presenting clearly states that all features are accessible through the standard API of the OS, a generic library is useless. In addition, devices such as RFID and fingerprint readers are often subject to security restrictions and may only be accessible with the SDK provided by the vendor.