# Capture keyboard input after a hotkey is pressed, without app focus

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode-scanner, hotkeys, hid

I have a bar code scanner that presents itself as a USB-HID keyboard.

How do I capture scanned bar codes in my c# WPF application, if the app currently does not have focus?

---

When a barcode is scanned, the scanner sends one or more configurable prefix keypress events, then the barcode itself, then some postfix keypresses.

If the application has focus, I can use the prefix hotkeys to focus a specific textbox; then the barcode is automatically entered into this textbox.

If the application does not have focus, how can I receive the barcode?

I could register a global hotkey via pInvoking `RegisterHotkey` from User32.dll, as outlined e.g. here:

- [How can I register a global hot key to say CTRL+SHIFT+(LETTER) using WPF and .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne)
- [Global hotkeys in WPF working from every window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377977/global-hotkeys-in-wpf-working-from-every-window)

But how do I capture the following keyboard events containing the bar code?

I am a little dubious about this approach as well, is there a simpler way to capture a string prefixed by a specific hotkey, without having focus?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164055/c-sharp-and-usb-hid-devices

Comment: That looks like it might work, but I would prefer a solution that did not involve an entire custom usb driver library, hopefully there is a simpler way to capture a couple key presses.

Comment: It should not require a custom USB driver library.  But you will need to rely on Windows API calls.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655023/how-do-i-read-input-from-a-usb-hid-device